# PHP - Calling a static function from an extended class

Tags: php, function, static

Let's say I have three classes set up as follows:

```
abstract Class A {

public static function testfunction() 
{
   print_r('Hi');
}

}

Class B extends A {

}

Class C extends A {

}
```

If I call testfunction through class B or C ie

```
B::testfunction();
```

Is there a way of printing out the name of the class that called it? So for example, the output could be

"Hi, this function was called by Class B"

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way of printing out the name of the class that called it?

Yes, in php 5.3, but not in earlier versions.

See: [Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) and [`get_called_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php)

In general, you can avoid this problem by using object instances, rather than static classes. It is often a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.3 you can use get_called_class() in your static test function. This uses late static binding.

Best wishes,
Fabian